# Can you allow gitlab kubernetes runners only in certain groups in Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Due to security concerns, I'd like to allow pipelines to use certain tagged runners only from specified groups (or projects). Is it possible?